# How to control the number of mappers when using parquet format

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, parquet

I am using parquet format for my hive tables . I see that storage for those tables is considerably improved .When I am running some queries on those tables,  number of mappers launched are very less as compared to when I am running same queries on same tables in text format. As a result of this, very less num of mappers are launched , hive queries on parquet format are taking long time to complete. ( I suspect this is because of small size parquet format ).
Is there any way to improve the running time on parquet format or in other words control the number of mappers while running hive queries ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hive with the Tez engine, the default input format (decides the number of splits of your data) is the ***HiveInputFormat*** class. You can change the input format class by using the `set` command like so

```
set hive.input.format=hive.tez.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat;
```

You can now control the number of input splits by varying the properties

`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize`

and set them to your desired number of bytes.

The ***CombineHiveInputFormat*** class also combines separate files into a single split in the case that each file has a size << dfs.block.size.